# How to get a local list and set it in a picklist? (VB, Infor PM)

Tags: vb6, reporting

Good day dear users,

I have to edit  a Report in Infor PM Application Studio, and I have a problem with using the list I have in the hyperblock in my Picklist. The Picklist is used for printing the different products in my report and has to have the same list members as the Hyperblock. The following vb code doesn't work. I can't manage to get the local list.

```
Sub  btnPrintCenter_Click () 
    Dim sList,newMembers(0)
    lvScale.SetCurSel 0, true
    newMembers(0) = Application.GetlocalListDefinition as String
    Application.SetPickListMembers "hpProduct\Objektliste",newMembers
    'sList = "PickListManager[lvRayon\Objektliste][PickListRayon]" 
    'sReturn = Spreadsheet.PickListManager (sList, false)
    lvRayon.List = "ProductsSumaPrintTdBEPF"
End sub
```

The help file in Infor PM mention using this:

*Returns XML definition of local list that is attached to the HyperBlock object.* 
Namespace: Spreadsheet

**Syntax
Visual Basic (Declaration)**

```
Public Function GetLocalListDefinition As String
```

I hope I have expressed myself clearly, please ask if something is not clear. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of trial and error, I have found the answer to my question. The script I used is the following:

```
Sub  btnPrintCenter_Click () 
Dim sList,newMembers(0)
lvScale.SetCurSel 0, true
newMembers(0) = Application.GetPickListMembers ("hpProduct\Local list")
Application.SetPickListMembers "PickListRayon\Objektliste",newMembers
sList = "PickListManager[hpProduct\Local list]"
sReturn = Spreadsheet.PickListManager (sList, false) 
End sub
```

With GetPickListMembers I am attributing the Hyperblock local list to a newMember. 
Maybe someone will find this usefull sometime in teh future.